# Not able to quick print .HTM files in Office 365

Tags: printing, office365

User running Office 2016, when they right click on an email with a .HTM attachment and select quick print the .htm files are not printing with the email.

This does not occur on any other file type.

I have selected the option File > Print > Print Options > Print attached files.

Printer is a network connected Konica Minolta C284e. I have updated the driver on our print server still no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After dealing with Microsoft support, they have told me it is a known issue.

There is a patch expect to be released within 50 days. So February 2016.

Just an update in case anyone sees this in between

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with the way Outlook handles attachments.  Outlook itself does not print them - it send them to your default program with a print command. So word prints DOCX files, excel prints XLSX, etc.

If you open the message and try to quick print just the .htm message you will most likely notice a popup asking you what you want to open it with.  If you select a browser it will open - but it won't print. I've tried thru word and my code editor - none of which will produce this behavior.  All I can suggest is playing around with different programs like maybe NotePadd++ or some other HTML editor to see what if any will work for you.